# Use Google Font Without Network Connection

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, dependencies, google-fonts

I have a webapp which will be run in a webview. It has a requirement that there be no external dependencies. I am using the Poppins font from Google.

I followed advice I found on stack overflow, and downloaded the Poppins font, converted it from `ttf` to `woff`, and then imported it into my css like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I'm loading my app and everything is working as expect, but I can still see network requests to get the Poppins font in the network tab of the Chrome dev tools. I believe this means that bundling my fonts has not had the desired effect of preventing them from being downloaded at run time. How do I fix this?

Comment: Prefer using fontsquirrel[dot]com  for downloading this one (Poppins)...

Comment: Did you remove the @import statement from your CSS which references Google’s CDN? (Or the `<link>` tags from the `<head>` of your HTML?) Is your old CSS being cached somewhere?

Comment: You may find [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-google-webfonts) useful.

Comment: Entries in the network tab are perfectly OK as long as they point to your local (server) directory URL. As suggested by @Brett Donald If you still see entries pointing to google URLs check your template for any `<link>` or  `<style>` or maybe `@import` rules within your main css elements still requesting the fonts from google.  BTW. you should prefer woff2 – according to [canuse statistics](https://caniuse.com/woff2) supported by  97.33% of browsers.

Comment: ... and as always triple-check your font urls/paths. Seriously, it is by far the most common error screwing up local font loading (2 . place  on a tier list would be syntax errors in the `@font-face` rule; 3. issues related to web bundlers – you would see an OTS parsing error).

Answer (score 0):

The server will try to get the font by sending a request to the url you have provided. I think that the only way to use a specific font without hosting that font and the client requesting it, is if the specified font is installed on the user's machine or if its a default system font.